# IMAP map_search() for ics files

Tags: php, email, imap

i wants to fetch email having only .ics files using IMAP in php

```
$emails = imap_search($inbox, 'ALL');
```

i am using above code for search i need some condition instead of "All" or imap_search by some extension(.ics) which gives me emails having .ics

Answer (score 0):

you ccan used this function to serach the perticular extation in your email.

```
<?php $keyword=".ics";
 $emails = imap_search($inbox,'BODY "'.$keyword.'"', SE_FREE, "UTF-8"); 
?>
```

Comment: Cant able to fetch .ics files having content-type text/calendar; charset=UTF-8

Comment: I think are saying right but you can think logical and serach that file like ics key word in your email

Comment: its an calendar attachment not key of body

Answer (score 0):

The search key `header content-disposition ".ics"` may or may not work. Depends on the server.

IMAP isn't quite well defined in this aspect.

```
  HEADER <field-name> <string>
     Messages that have a header with the specified field-name (as
     defined in [RFC-2822]) and that contains the specified string
     in the text of the header (what comes after the colon).  If the
     string to search is zero-length, this matches all messages that
     have a header line with the specified field-name regardless of
     the contents.
```

So the field name has to be as defined in 2822. But email messages contain three kinds of header (the top-level message header, embedded message/822 headers and finally bodypart headers), and all three use that syntax. I suspect that most servers search either the first kind of header or all three, and that the RFC's author had in mind the first two.

So why don't you just try the search key with the target server, and if it works, it works.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you friends i got the exact solution of my problem

i am opening connection first by `imap_open` then searching emails

```
$imap_search($inbox, 'ALL')
```

then fetching structure of emails by `imap_fetchstructure` and from that structure i am getting ics files from attachments and finally form attachments i am getting imap body `imap_base64(imap_fetchbody($mbox, $mid, 2));`

it will gives me actually .ics calendar content